# Union filesystem with "versioned" filenames?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Do you know if there is a unioned fs for GNU/Linux that shows also "shadowed" files with slightly different names?
I.E. if I have two fs like:

```
root1
+dir1
+dir2
 +file1
 +file2
 +file3

root2
+dir1
+dir2
 +file1
 +file2
 +file4
```

The resulting "unioned" fs should result:

```
unioned
+dir1
+dir2
 +file1
 +file1.1
 +file2
 +file2.1
 +file3
```

So that it could be possible to quickly check differences between the "unioned" fs

It seems that UnionFS and Aufs do not offer this option

Thank you

Comment: Well, I’d go as far as saying that this would undermine the basic concept of these file systems. If you want to diff directory trees, why not simply use `diff`?

Comment: because I need to merge geographical spread backups (created with multiple rsync) by quickly check differences
with diff/meld/etc. it would be very time consuming to diff every fs couple I have at least 5 different backups)

Comment: If you can mount them, you can use `diff`. I fail to see the problem, sorry.

Comment: time consuming (300k files per fs)

while with unioning I could superimpose them and use tools like rdfind (duplicate finder) on a per-directory basis

Comment: also, bear in mind that I'm not interested in choosing the youngest or the prioritized file of every layer, I also need to check if they are sane

Comment: @atrent were you ever able to try git-annex?

Comment: Yes! And it's awesome (with some manageable glitch). I've even created a sort of a GUI-helper to track and manage git-annexes with many remotes and files, see https://github.com/atrent/AdMinchiam/tree/master/ga-gui

Comment: Well, at the moment I'm experimenting with git-annex per se, I have to try your "merging" proposal yet, I will do it when I fully understand git-annex :)

Comment: a final remark, your merging proposal is **the best solution so far** (and probably the only one until someone writes a unionfs with the feature I look for), the only drawback is that I should 'git-annex init' (and reciprocally add remotes) every backup I have to merge: a very time consuming operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using `git-annex`:

First, we will setup the test files:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# faster than /dev/urandom
randfile='openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero'
dd='dd bs=1M count=5 iflag=fullblock'

for I in 1 2
do
  mkdir root$I
  cd root$I
  for J in 1 2
  do
    mkdir dir$J
    if [ -e dir2 ]
    then
      cd dir2
      eval $randfile | eval $dd of=file1
      eval $randfile | eval $dd of=file2
      if [ `pwd | grep root1` ]; then
        eval $randfile | eval $dd of=file3
      elif [ `pwd | grep root2` ]; then
        eval $randfile | eval $dd of=file4
      fi
      cd ..
    fi
  done
  cd ..
done
```

This creates the directories, with binary files containing random data. At this point the files are:

```
user@host$ find root? -path '*/.git*' -prune -o -print | sort -n 
root1
root1/dir1
root1/dir2
root1/dir2/file1
root1/dir2/file2
root1/dir2/file3
root2
root2/dir1
root2/dir2
root2/dir2/file1
root2/dir2/file2
root2/dir2/file4
```

Now, we initialize the repos and perform a sync:

```
cd root1
  git init
  git annex init 'root1'
  git remote add root2 ../root2
  #git annex direct
  git annex add .
  git commit -a -m 'Files added.'
cd ..
cd root2
  git init
  git annex init 'root1'
  git remote add root1 ../root1
  #git annex direct
  git annex add .
  git commit -a -m 'Files added.'
cd ..
mkdir unioned
cd unioned
  git init
  git annex init 'unioned'
  git remote add root1 ../root1
  git remote add root2 ../root2
  git annex add . 
  git commit -a -m 'Files added.'
  git annex sync
cd ..
```

At this point, the contents of `unioned/` are:

```
user@host$ find root? unioned -path '*/.git*' -prune -o -print | sort -n
root1
root1/dir1
root1/dir2
root1/dir2/file1
root1/dir2/file2
root1/dir2/file3
root2
root2/dir1
root2/dir2
root2/dir2/file1
root2/dir2/file2
root2/dir2/file4
unioned
unioned/dir2
unioned/dir2/file1
unioned/dir2/file1.variant-065a
unioned/dir2/file1.variant-a33e
unioned/dir2/file2
unioned/dir2/file2.variant-08f3
unioned/dir2/file2.variant-75c4
unioned/dir2/file3
unioned/dir2/file4
```

Where `*.variant-*` link back to the different files in the different repositories. Also, `unioned` still contains no data until we conduct a `git annex get`. For now, `git annex list` shows where the files are located and/or sourced from:

```
user@host$ cd unioned; git annex list
here
|root1
||root2
|||web
||||
__X_ dir2/file1.variant-065a
_X__ dir2/file1.variant-a33e
__X_ dir2/file2.variant-08f3
_X__ dir2/file2.variant-75c4
_X__ dir2/file3
__X_ dir2/file4
```

An alternative in longer form is `git annex whereis`. Finally, to resolve the conflicts, and propagate the merge, from inside `unioned/dir2`:

```
cd unioned/dir2
git annex get # retrieve the actual content
git annex unlock # unlock the files - replace the symlinks with the actual repofiles
rm file1
git mv file1.variant-065a file1
git rm -f file1.variant-a33e
rm file2
git mv file2.variant-75c4 file2
git rm -f file2.variant-08f3
git annex add . # "commits" the changes, converts files back into symlinks
git annex sync  # propagates the changes back to the other repos
```

Which yields:

```
git annex sync
commit  ok
pull root2 
ok
pull root1 
ok
push root2 
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (37/37), 2.67 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 37 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../root2
   e5df80f..720b34b  git-annex -> synced/git-annex
   b055385..ad8c5c2  master -> synced/master
ok
push root1 
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (37/37), 2.67 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 37 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../root1
   e5df80f..720b34b  git-annex -> synced/git-annex
   b055385..ad8c5c2  master -> synced/master
ok
```

Finally, a `git annex list` shows where these files are located after the sync: the `unioned/` directory has copies of all files, chosen from the different servers as above.

---

`git-annex` also has a [direct mode](https://git-annex.branchable.com/direct_mode/) which operates directly on the filesystem without the use of symlinks.

Setting this up for use on remote computers is a matter of setup up remotes over ssh using standard git, however it's behaviour is described here: http://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/using_ssh_remotes/

The overall walkthrough of *git annex* is located here: http://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at the file-system level, since you need to see/maintain differences between versions. If they are text files - then `git` http://git-scm.com/ will provide a good solution. `git` is a version control system used for source code, and handles both comparing multiple directories of files (aka repositories), but branching, diffs and merges.

If you cannot use `git`, then rsync will provide a solution, but you will need to manually develop a solution to examine the files you wish to compare or merge. With git these differences are automatically tracked.

If they are mostly binary files - you may want to do something with rsync. For instance, with the following script:
To setup the test:

```
set -x
for DIR in a b c ; do mkdir $DIR ; done
for DIR in `ls -d ?`; do
  echo "TESTMSG1-$DIR" >> $DIR/A;
  echo "TESTMSG2-$DIR" >> $DIR/B;
  echo "TESTMSG3-$DIR" >> $DIR/C;
  done
ls
ls -R
grep -r $ ?
```

And to execute the test, with `-av` for verbose archive copy, and `-c` to compare the files with a checksum, and `-b --suffix=` to create backups of files with a timestamp for later comparison:

```
rsync -avc -b --suffix=-$(date +%s.bk) a/ b
ls -R
grep -r $ ?
find . -name "*.bk"
```

We show that the files are copied, a time-stamped `.bk` suffix is added, then you can find the backup files for further analysis: `find . -name "*.bk"`

```
$ sh test.sh
...output deleted for brevity...
+ ls
a  b  c  test.sh
+ ls -R
a  b  c  test.sh

./a:
A  B  C
./b:
A  B  C
./c:
A  B  C
+ grep -r $ a b c
a/A:TESTMSG1-a
a/B:TESTMSG2-a
a/C:TESTMSG3-a
b/A:TESTMSG1-b
b/B:TESTMSG2-b
b/C:TESTMSG3-b
c/A:TESTMSG1-c
c/B:TESTMSG2-c
c/C:TESTMSG3-c

+ date +%s.bk
+ rsync -avc -b --suffix=-1403746846.bk a/ b
sending incremental file list
A
B
C
sent 300 bytes  received 73 bytes  746.00 bytes/sec
total size is 33  speedup is 0.09
+ ls -R
a  b  c  test.sh

./a:
A  B  C
./b:
A  A-1403746846.bk  B  B-1403746846.bk  C  C-1403746846.bk
./c:
A  B  C
+ grep -r $ a b c
a/A:TESTMSG1-a
a/B:TESTMSG2-a
a/C:TESTMSG3-a
b/A:TESTMSG1-a
b/A-1403746846.bk:TESTMSG1-b
b/B:TESTMSG2-a
b/B-1403746846.bk:TESTMSG2-b
b/C:TESTMSG3-a
b/C-1403746846.bk:TESTMSG3-b
c/A:TESTMSG1-c
c/B:TESTMSG2-c
c/C:TESTMSG3-c

+find . -name "*.bk"
./b/B-1403746846.bk
./b/C-1403746846.bk
./b/A-1403746846.bk
```

Another alternative is to use ZFS snapshots to 'mirror' the directories in to the same 'namespace.' Pseudo code for these steps (since I don't have zfs in front of me) would be something like:

```
for X in (a b c); do 
  zfs snapshot zfs-destination@baseline
  rsync -avc /src-$X/ zfs-destination
  zfs snapshot zfs-destination@$X
  diff -r zfs-destination/ zfs-destination/.zfs/snapshot/$X/
  # analyze diff files and validate changes to commit
  # restore files to not change from .zfs/snapshot/baseline
done
```

Not that you 'can' loop as a script, because of the manual requirement to analyse the patches, but repeating the above steps for each source dir would give you both the ability to merge, and a complete history through snapshots. Replace 'a b c' with something like `date -Is` to timestamp the snapshots.

I overlooked the `zfs diff` command. The diff line above should be:

```
zfs diff -FH zfs-destination/ zfs-destination@baseline | \
  awk '/^[+MR]\tF/ {print $3}' > list
```

Where awk selects (+) for added files (M) for modified (R) for renamed. This is much faster than the recursive diff on the directories.

Comment: Thanks! First note: I know about git (I use it every day) but my need does not involve (only) text files, moreover they are many (half a million) and they come from scattered (geographically spread) backups that I periodically (continuously) run using rsync. Then, sometimes (not frequently, luckily) I have a disk crash and I need to merge the backups (since they are in slightly different states. At the moment I use rdfind (to clear duplicates) and meld/diff/etc to verify remaining files (I cannot rely on timestamps because my last disk problem was on the master disk and I noticed it too late)

Comment: Second note: thanks again! I did not remember about the backup option of rsync, I think that solves (albeit with more disk I/O) my problem for now.

Comment: @atrent there is also 'unison' http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/ I haven't used it much, but it's more tuned to merge rather than newest replaces old like rsync, and it may be useful.

Comment: @atrent also, if this solved your question, please mark the answer appropriately. thanks.

Comment: Unison is one of the worst programs I've ever seen... unusable at best. The rsync option is not a complete solution, so I leave this question open.

Comment: If the zfs isn't viable - I'm out of ideas - maybe one of the clustering file systems, so you can write to one cluster from all sources and then snapshot?

Comment: I was referring to the first part of your rsync proposal, shame on me, the ZFS could be a solution, let me try it

Comment: could ZFS be substituted by btrfs?

Comment: Possibly - a lot of the concepts are similar between the two regarding snapshots.

Comment: You mentioned that you don't want to use git, because there are binary files involved. What if, rather than eliminating git, you could control the growth and size of the git repository by truncating the history after each merge. This would allow the comparison/merge capabilities without the linear growth with binary changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository.

Comment: Or, there's some add-ons for git and mercurial: hg with the *Largefiles* extension, [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) manages files with git, without putting them into the repo itself http://stackoverflow.com/a/6635160/222519 It looks promising, since it can help move the files for you, but in the repo it only stores simlinks and metadata (hashes) so it can compare the files. I think `git-annex` is your answer.

Comment: From [git-annex docs](https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex/): "Merge conflicts are automatically handled by sync. When two conflicting versions of a file have been committed, both will be added to the tree, under different filenames. For example, file "foo" would be replaced with "foo.somekey" and "foo.otherkey".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question seems to be "not at the moment".

Workarounds have been proposed, they are based:

- on a notorious tool (rsync, with the backup option activated)
- on special filesystems (such as ZFS or btrfs) offering "snapshotting"

Both proposals involve heavy I/O because they create e new filesystem instead of mapping the existent ones into a virtual filesystem.